"Up to Ring homomorphism, every Algebra $A$ arises from a subring of $A$ that lies in $Z(A)$"
I understand a R-algebra as follows:
Given $R$ is unital ring and a Ring homomorphism  $f: R \rightarrow A$ and $f(R)$ is contained in center of $A$ then $A$ is a R-algebra.
Question: The statement: Up to Ring homomorphism every R-algebra arises from a subring of the center of $A$
Does it mean: Given a fixed Ring homomorphism, the different R-algebras are determined by the different subrings of A that lie in the Center of A? So, every R-algebra must necessarily be a Ring over its own subring (As in a Module structure)?
Thanks

The word "arises" there seems vague.

I mean, given a subring $R_1$ of $Z(A),$ there might be two or more different ways to find $f:R\to R_1.$ Not sure. So it really depends on what you mean by "arises."

Hi @ThomasAndrews arises can mean "induced"? As in the Subrings $R_1 \in Z(A)$ , Naturally gives the $R_1$ algebra.

Induced how? There must be an actual meaning to the question to be able to solve it. As it is, you seem to be letting $R$ to be a variable, but then we are not seeking $R$-algebras, we are look for all ways to make an algebra over any ring.

Let $K$ be a Subring in the center of $R$ then the module R over K is precisely the K-Algebra? This is well-defined. The claims seems to be the only way to construct an Algebra over a Ring is to take the Subring Algebra.

Take the example of a Polynomial Ring over a Field. $F[x]$ , then the only possible $K-$ Algebras are the field $F$ and Trivial subring $0$
